# How to convert the accumulated data of 'fflate' zip stream to blob for download

Tags: browser, stream, zip

The application will create a large data in GBs. After storing to an array and the passing to zip() worked to a limit , which the heap filled. So my plan is

- convert each line using ZipDeflate .push()
- ondata store to an array
- convert the array to blob that can be saved as a zip file

findings

- data is an Uint8Array
- new Blob([mergedDatas]) was not a zip file

```
  const zippedData = []
  const zip = new Zip();
  zip.ondata = (err, data, final) => {
        if (!err) {
          zippedData.push(data)
          if (final) {
            // Here I want the zipped data to be downloaded
          }
        }
      };
    
  const frames = new ZipDeflate(exportName + '.lsf', {
    level: 9,
  });
 zip.add(frames);
 frames.push(header); // this is a uintd binary data
// there is lot of loops and things that will generate GBs of data eg. below two lines
 frames.push(numberToBytes(branch.name));
 frames.push(ColorByteArray);
// end of loop 
 frames.push(new Uint8Array(0), true);
 zip.end();
```

Answer (score 2):

Finally found myself

```js
  let processedZipStreams = [];
  zip.ondata = async (err, dat, final) => {
    if (err) {
    } else {
      processedZipStreams.push(dat);
      generatorInstance.next();
      if (final) {
        SaveAs(
          new Blob(processedZipStreams, { type: 'application/octet-stream' }),
          exportName,
          true
        );
        callback(100);
        const duration = performance.now() - start;
        console.log(duration / 1000);
      }
    }
  };
```

processed ZipStreams can be packed to a blob and downloaded